# 64bit com dll not visible in vs 2010 a

Tags: reference, com, .net-4.0, 64-bit

I have a com dll (64 bit) which i am able to register using regsvr32 (from windows\system32 folder). the registration is successfull. but when i try to add the dll to my c# project (vs2010 .net 4.0) the dll is not visible in the file open dialog (even though the file is visible if browsed using windows explorer). this behaviour is in windows 2008 R2. but in windows 7 i am able to register and add reference to the dll using vs2010. but in windows 7 if i try to debug the project, i am getting dll not registered error. but i am able to publish the project without issues, and the published version is working fine in IIS7.5 of the Windows 2008 r2 server which i am not able to add reference using vs2010. strange problem, can any one please advice.

Comment: Multiple problems, caused by VS still using 32-bit.  You'll need to run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop assembly.  And remove the jitter forcing on your EXE project so the program runs in 64-bit mode.

Comment: hi,Thank you for the response, but i couldn't understand, can you explain bit more ?